# Get n strings from Linq

Tags: c#, linq

I am trying to get every 5 "NewNumber" int's to insert in to var q. Let's say there are 20  records returned by UniqueNumbers, I would like to get 1-5, 6-10, 11-15, 16-20 and then have Number1 = 1,Number2 = 2,Number3 = 3,Number4 = 4,Number5 = 5 passed to var q the first time, followed by Number1 = 6, Number2 = 7, Number3 = 8, Number4 = 9, Number5 = 10 and so on...

```
  var UniqueNumbers =
            from t in Numbers
            group t by new { t.Id } into g
            select new
            {
                NewNumber = g.Key.Id,

            };

 UniqueNumbers.Skip(0).Take(5)


 var q = new SolrQueryInList("NewNumber1", "NewNumber2","NewNumber3","NewNumber4","NewNumber5");
```

Comment: It isn't very clear what it is your trying to accomplish here (especially the last sentence). Could you please elaborate?

Comment: Does the `SolrQueryInList` take strings or integers?

Comment: @James UniqueNumbers contains a large volume of numbers, instead of querying the db for them 1 at a time I am trying to query 5 at a time. So I need to pass every 5 to var q

Comment: @nintendojunkie strings

Comment: You say that you're "passing every 5 to var q", but your code sample is defining q based on a call to `SolrQueryInList`.  Are you trying to pass the numbers into the `SolrQueryInList` method?  Why are they strings and not integers?

Comment: @nintendojunkie yes I am trying to pass them to the query. They must be strings in SolrQueryInList.

Comment: Can you give example on input and desired output.

Comment: @Magnus input: Name, Id; Jay,1 Jim,2 Pete,3 Sam,4 John,5 Steve,6 Marty,7 Matt,8 Mike,9 Dave,10  Output:1,2,3,4,5 as an array I suppose. Needs to be passed to the query method var q. Followed by output 6,7,8,9,10

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < UniqueNumbers.Count / 5; i++)
{
    // Gets the next 5 numbers
    var group = UniqueNumbers.Skip(i * 5).Take(5);

    // Convert the numbers to strings
    var stringNumbers = group.Select(n => n.ToString()).ToList();

    // Pass the numbers into the method
    var q = new SolrQueryInList(stringNumbers[0], stringNumbers[1], ...
}
```

You'll have to figure out how to manage boundary conditions, like if `UniqueNumbers.Count` is not divisible by 5.  You might also be able to modify `SolrQueryInList` to take a list of numbers so that you don't have to index into the list 5 times for that call.

EDIT:

Jim Mischel pointed out that looping over a `Skip` operation gets expensive fast.  Here's a variant that keeps your place, rather than starting at the beginning of the list every time:

```
var remaining = UniqueNumbers;
while(remaining.Any())
{
    // Gets the next 5 numbers
    var group = remaining.Take(5);

    // Convert the numbers to strings
    var stringNumbers = group.Select(n => n.ToString()).ToList();

    // Pass the numbers into the method
    var q = new SolrQueryInList(stringNumbers[0], stringNumbers[1], ...

    // Update the starting spot
    remaining = remaining.Skip(5);
}
```

Comment: Although this will work, it's a terrible solution to the problem. This gets to be very expensive if your `UniqueNumbers` list is long. It's an n^2 operation. So if you have 1,000 items, the first time it skips 0, the next time it skips 5, the next time it skips 10, etc. In addition, this won't work with something like a `File.ReadLines` enumerator, because you scan the enumerable multiple times. You're better off doing `UniqueNumbers.ToArray()` and then operating on segments of the array.

Answer (score 2):

If you have a list of items, you can easily separate them into groups of five like this:

```
int count = 0;
var groupsOfFive =
    from t in remaining
    group t by count++ / 5 into g
    select new { Key=g.Key, Numbers = g };
```

And then:

```
foreach (var g in groupsOfFive)
{
    var parms = g.Numbers.Select(n => n.ToString()).ToArray();
    var q = new SolrQueryInList(parms[0], parms[1], parms[2], parms[3], parms[4]);
}
```

I think what you want is some variation on that.

### Edit

Another way to do it, if for some reason you don't want to do the grouping, would be:

```
var items = remaining.Select(n => n.ToString()).ToArray();
for (int current = 0; current < remaining.Length; remaining += 5)
{
    var q = new SolrQueryInList(
        items[current],
        items[current+1],
        items[current+2],
        items[current+3],
        items[current+4]);
}
```

Both of these assume that the number of items is evenly divisible by 5. If it's not, you have to handle the possibility of not enough parameters.